# Cannot send request to controller

Tags: magento-1.9, url

Path to function in controller is `src/app/code/local/Api/LiteGento/controllers/AgentController.php`.
Function name is `getAuthTokenAction`. 
I tried go to the mysite.loc/liteGento/agent/getAuthToken, but response is 404.
Where is my mistake?

My controller:

```
public function getAuthTokenAction() {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getParam('login');
        $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');

        if(empty($login) || empty($password)) {
            $error = Mage::helper('litegento')->renderError(14);
            $this->renderResponse($error);
            return;
        }

        $agent = Mage::getModel('agent/agent')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('auth_token', 'password_hash', 'websiteIds','status'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('email', array('eq' => $login))
            ->getFirstItem();

        if(!$agent->getId()) {
            $error = Mage::helper('litegento')->renderError(21);
            $this->renderResponse($error);
            return;
        }

        if($agent->getStatus() != 1) {
            $error = Mage::helper('litegento')->renderError(24);
            $this->renderResponse($error);
            return;
        }

        if(!in_array(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(), explode(',', $agent->getData('websiteIds')))){
            $error = Mage::helper('litegento')->renderError(22);
            $this->renderResponse($error);
            return;
        }

        $hash = $agent->getPasswordHash();
        if(!$hash || !Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($password, $hash)) {
            $error = Mage::helper('litegento')->renderError(18);
            $this->renderResponse($error);
            return;
        }

        if(!$agent->getAuthToken()) {
            $date = new DateTime();
            $newAuthToken = md5(uniqid($agent->getId(), true).$date->getTimestamp());
            $newAuthToken = substr($newAuthToken, 0, 31);
            $agent->setAuthToken($newAuthToken);
            $agent->save();
        }elseif (strlen($agent->getAuthToken()) > 32){
            $newAuthToken = substr($agent->getAuthToken(), 0, 31);
            $agent->setAuthToken($newAuthToken);
            $agent->save();
        }

        $this->renderResponse(array(
            'Status' => 'SUCCESS',
            'Token'  => 'AuthToken-' . $agent->getAuthToken(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Please share your content controller, did your module `Api/LiteGento` works fine ?

Comment: @Prince I think yes, but I edit it. I think, that false with url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some **rooter** in `config.xml` like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Api_LiteGento>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Api_LiteGento>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <api_liteGento>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Api_LiteGento</module>
                    <frontName>litegento</frontName>
                </args>
            </api_liteGento>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now you access to your controller like this: `litegento/agentcontroller/getauthtoken`

Comment: TY, it was my mistake. It was wrong frontName